# Global variable undefined in require file

Tags: javascript, global-variables, undefined, global

Error: "TILE_SIZE is not defined". In the constructor of World class.

When I try using:

```
global.TILE_SIZE = 64;
```

it works, but when declaring it with var, let or const it is undefined. Why does this happen?

app.js:

```
const TILE_SIZE = 64;
let WORLDS = [];

...

let World = require("./World");

...

function init() {
    WORLDS[0] = new World(0, [...]);
}

...

init();
```

World.js:

```
class World {
    constructor(id, boundmap) {
        this.id = id;
        this.boundmap = boundmap;
        this.width = boundmap[0].length * TILE_SIZE;
        this.height = boundmap.length * TILE_SIZE;
    }

    ...
}

module.exports = World;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because node module are executed in a function (the `require` function I think) So the `const`, `let` and `var` variables are scoped to that function but the `global.TILE_SIZE = 64;` will be placed on the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in `require()` function implementation.
If you defining `TILE_SIZE` with either `var`, `let` or `const`, then its scope is `app.js` file, which is not the `global` object.
So, inside `World.js` you dont have access to `app.js`'s scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.js` and `World.js` are part of different contexts aka closures. The `TILE_SIZE` variable can only be accessed inside of `app.js`.

You would need to explicitly pass in the `TILE_SIZE` variable as an argument to `World`'s constructor.

[Learn More about Closures here](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/lets-learn-javascript-closures-66feb44f6a44#.gne7c9ac0)